# What is the Customs limit for alcohol import to Turkey?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, turkey, turkish-airlines

I am travelling soon to Turkey and wish to bring some nice French wine as gifts.

I have seen mention that only two 750-ml bottles of wine may be brought into the country (or one 1-liter bottle). I have also seen elsewhere that 5 litres of alcoholic beverages is the limit (which would be enough for a crate of six bottles).

What is the correct limit so that I can pack appropriately without needing to pour nice burgundy down the drain at London Heathrow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [government website](https://www.ktb.gov.tr/EN-120416/duty-free-goods.html) says:

> 1 (100 cl) or 2 (75cl or 70 cl) bottles of wine and/or spirits

One-liter bottles are more common in DF stores – since they are often, like here, the maximum allowance – whereas 70 cl (spirits) and 75 cl (wines) are more typical of domestic markets. It seems they decided to let you bring in duty-free either 1 liter in one bottle or 1.4/1.5 liters in two bottles.

It seems like this is a fixed limit: in many countries, if you have more than that you will pay tax on the excess. But here it looks like you can't do that, and have to leave the excess in storage to take back with you when you leave Turkey.

Comment: Thanks - so to be clear does that limit apply even to bottles bought in duty free, in either the departure or arrival airport, or would these be exempt?

Comment: That limit applies to any alcohol you're carrying. The shops may be called duty-free (meaning that their prices do not include any duties/taxes), and they're happy to sell you anything, but if your purchases exceed the allowance at your country of arrival, it's your responsibility.

Comment: What's the penalty for being caught with extra bottles in one's suitcase?

Comment: Hm, indeed the government website mentions "wine and/or spirits" (either 1 or 1.4/1.5 liters) only in the Turkish Duty Free Shops section. But what about import? When me and my girlfriend went from Georgia (country) by bus, we brought 2 * 3 liter jugs with us. When the Turkish customs officer said there is a problem, I pointed out to him that there are two of us and he said it's ok. So I came here to find out what the exact limits are and found this...

Answer (score 0):

Correct limit is one bottle of 1 litter or two bottles of 750 ml of wine or spirits. If you exceed this limit, your alcohol products will be taken to airport storage that you can take back upon your departure from Turkey (airport of arrival and departure should be the same) during next 3 months and storage fee should be paid. So it's basically waste to bring more than two bottles of 750ml.